# How can I include all the dialogues in the loop but to avoid the exception out of index?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue[] dialogue;

    private int dialogueNum = 0;
    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        if (FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>() != null)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue[dialogueNum]);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == true)
        {
            if (dialogueNum == dialogue.Length)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                dialogueNum += 1;
                FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue[dialogueNum]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example if I have 3 dialogues in the array it will make the first one then will throw the exception IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array and then will do the last one.

If I will add  -1 in the condition checking:

```
if (dialogueNum == dialogue.Length - 1)
```

Then it will not throw the exception but will do only the first one and the last one the second dialogue will never be done.

And maybe it's better to make it in a StartCoroutine instead in the Update ? With a public int array to decide how much to wait between each dialogue ?

I want to add the int array variable to be able to decide how much to wait between each dialogue. For example between dialogue 0 and 1 wait one second and between dialogue 1 and 2 wait 5 seconds.

Comment: As you already mentioned, I would recommend you to try it with a Coroutine and using a for-loop instead of your current structure in the Update-method.

Comment: If your current code is working for you, then just change the order of the two statements inside the `else`

Comment: Walk through this code on paper, and you should see the problem.  Go step-by-step, line-by-line.  Keep track of the value of every variable.  You'll definitely see the problem, and it should be fairly obvious how to fix it.

Comment: @LouisIngenthron Right the problem was I was raising the value of dialogueNum before starting the new dialogue. Moving the line dialogueNum += 1; after starting the new dialogue solved the exception problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as moving dialogueNum += 1 after the StartDialogue call:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == true)
    {
        // Lets assume dialogueNum is in the last index, dialogueNum = 2
        // So dialogueNum == dialogue.Length is false
        if (dialogueNum == dialogue.Length) // THIS IS FALSE
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // If dialogueNum +=1 was here, dialogueNum would have been 3
            FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>tartDialogue(dialogue[dialogueNum]);
            // Then we try to get the element at index 3 and get the out of index exception

            dialogueNum += 1; // MOVE dialogueNum += 1 HERE!
        }
    }
}
```